# SSRS getting result from SQL Stored Procedure return value

Tags: reporting-services

Basically, I have a stored procedure that does some checking and will return a 1 or 0.

It is not a column, field name, something like

```
IF (some logic) RETURN 1
....
...
RETURN 0
```

I don't know what to put for the field source...

I am trying to make a text box show/hidden based on the result of the SP being a 1 or 0.

```
=IIF(something here, false, true)
```

Is there an issue with trying to get the return value to be used instead of columns?

[image: Source]

[image: No results]

Comment: It seems, at least going to an old article (https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2008/08/use-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-ssrs/) that you cannot use return values in SSRS

Comment: So, unless someone has a way around this, my solution, which kind of sucks, was to modify the SP and instead of RETURN 0 or RETURN 1, I did a BEGIN/END block around SELECT 0 (or 1) AS MyVariable and a RETURN (to not process further), so that SSRS could have an actual result with a column named MyVariable... works, but as Mr. Horse would say... Hmmmm, no sir, I don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like this in your dataset query

```
DECLARE @returnvalue int
EXEC @returnvalue = SP_SomeProc

SELECT @returnValue as TheResult
```

The dataset will return a field called `TheResult` containing the value from the SP

Answer (score 0):

SSRS datasets expect to get column names from the query.

1. In your stored procedure use SELECT statements to return values.

   ```
   IF (some logic) SELECT 1 as MyResult
   ...
   SELECT 0 as MyResult
   ```
2. In your dataset properties, reference the procedure as usual and supply any parameters to it as needed. You should see the "MyResult" field under the dataset name.
3. In your expression you would check the result like this:

   ```
   =IIf( First(Fields!MyResult.Value, "SP_Dataset") = 1, true, false )
   ```

If you were thinking of sending different values into the stored procedure in each cell with this expression, that will not work because each dataset is only evaluated once. If that is the desired behavior, you would need to check all the rows in the initial SQL instead.